# SUMO: duaIterate with MSA

Tags: sumo

I am just a beginner SUMO user, maybe that is the reason I am not sure how I should create a duaIterate simulation with MSA. My problem is the following: when I call the --MSA the program encounters some kind of problem. Can you give me an example or some explanation of what could be the problem?

python /opt/homebrew/opt/sumo/share/sumo/tools/assign/duaIterate.py -n SUMO/basic/basic.net.xml -r SUMO/basic/test.rou.xml --MSA

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/opt/homebrew/opt/sumo/share/sumo/tools/assign/duaIterate.py", line 721, in

```
sys.exit(main())
```

File "/opt/homebrew/opt/sumo/share/sumo/tools/assign/duaIterate.py", line 521, in main

```
options = argParser.parse_args(args=args)
```

File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sumo/1.18.0/share/sumo/tools/sumolib/options.py", line 357, in parse_args

```
return self.parse_known_args(args, namespace, True)[0]
```

File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sumo/1.18.0/share/sumo/tools/sumolib/options.py", line 433, in parse_known_args

```
unknown_args.insert(1, namespace.remaining_args[0])
```

IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option is (was) called `-MSA` and not `--MSA` and it has changed in current main branch already.